# How to use Access Trail and other services to log and notify new inbound IP requests on APIs?

Tags: ibm-cloud, accesstrail

My current project has a handful of apps that each have a handful of APIs. My fellow team and I were tasked with looking into Access Trail to see if we can track new IP requests. We can see the logs coming from the apps which have the inbound IP but there isn't a field that specifically is just the IP by itself. Does anyone have insight on this and how to set it up to alert someone of new IP requests?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too general to get  a good answer here. Stack Overflow really requires knowing more specifically what you have already tried, including relevant code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for the full guidelines. Questions like this about Bluemix functionality really belong on IBM developerWorks Answers: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/

Answer (score 0):

Access Trail logs API calls to CF applications and Bluemix services (for a list of integrated services with Access Trail, see https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/AccessTrail/at_integration.html#at_integration ) that  run in the space of your Bluemix organization where the Access Trail service is provisioned.

In Access Trail, you can see the initiator's IP address by looking at the field initiator.host.address.

You can use the Kibana dashboard to monitor the logs, and IPs that are not trusted (https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/AccessTrail/at_manage_log.html#at_dashboard_ov).

Answer (score 0):

Access Trail does not have an integrated alert notification system. However, you can use a cURL command to export a subset of API audit records that are logged into the Access Trail log on a specific date (https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/AccessTrail/at_manage_log.html#at_get_events_by_range_cli)
or you can use cURL command to export logs for one day (https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/AccessTrail/at_manage_log.html#at_export_data_cli). Then, you can manage the records locally.